# Can I use Mono to build a deployment package for an ASP.NET Web App?

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, mono

Does mono support the creation of deployment packages in the same way VS2010 does? (The .zip file with a .cmd file that automates deployment to IIS).

My continuous integration server is a linux box and it would be nice to hand out deployment packages from there. However, this seems like an advanced feature that mono probably doesn't support... does anyone out there know for sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own here. It looks like there is no way to do this at this time. I had to revert to using MSbuild instead.